# Is it possible to configure different ssh ports for different users?

Tags: ssh, openssh

We can change the default port settings at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` but the manual does not provide any information if we can assign different ports for different users? Is setting up multiple ports for a service possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Example of a server which listens on ports 666 and 667, and only allows users whose names start with "a" through port 666:

```
Port 666
Port 667
Match LocalPort 666
        AllowUsers a*
```

Go read about all those directives in the [`sshd_config(5)`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#Match) manpage.

Comment: On my system, it says no such manual exist!

Comment: [Come on](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#Match)